# How do I connect to a database I created in HostGator?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Edit: I have googled and searched, read what I could find of their documentation. Even chatted with them. The chatter could help me. This is why I reach to you.

I am a complete beginner and I am having some troubles getting started with databases on hostgator. I guess my question also is valid using other hosts.

I created a db through the cpanel in hostgator and added a user to it.

I copied this script into a test.php in my /public_html/ folder and ran it on my site.

In the script I used the name, user and password from the database and user I previously created in cpanel. This database I can see using phpMyAdmin.

```
<?php
  try
  {
    //open the database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:localhost;dbname=user_db', 'user_username', 'password');

    //create the database
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE Dogs (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Breed TEXT, Name TEXT, Age INTEGER)");    

    //insert some data...
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO Dogs (Breed, Name, Age) VALUES ('Labrador', 'Tank', 2);".
               "INSERT INTO Dogs (Breed, Name, Age) VALUES ('Husky', 'Glacier', 7); " .
               "INSERT INTO Dogs (Breed, Name, Age) VALUES ('Golden-Doodle', 'Ellie', 4);");

    //now output the data to a simple html table...
    print "<table border=1>";
    print "<tr><td>Id</td><td>Breed</td><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>";
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Dogs');
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      print "<tr><td>".$row['Id']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['Breed']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['Age']."</td></tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";

    // close the database connection
    $db = NULL;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

This worked, which is nice, but it created a file in my /public_html/ folder called 'localhost;dbname=user_db'

My issue is that I thought I was connecting to the database I created using cpanel, but when I open phpMyAdmin, that database is empty.

How do I change that script to talk to the database I created using cpanel so that I can reach it using phpMyAdmin?

Edit 2:
So I learned that I need to use mysql, not sqlite because phpMyAdmin is based on MySQL.

Also, using the script from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp I was able to connect! So, success! Thank you @mituw16 and @Fred -ii-  for helping me! :D

Comment: *"How do I connect to a database I created in HostGator?"* - Read their documentation.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yes, I edited my post. I have tried that. Even chatted with them.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it returns any errors.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I put it right after the line with new PDO(...)  Exception : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table Dogs already exists

Comment: Then, make up a new file, minus the table creation code with the exceptions code I gave you.

Comment: @Fred -ii- then I get no errors.

Comment: @ToreS Please see my answer, the code that Fred-ii- is giving you is good (you only need to run the table creation code one time), but you still have the issue in your initial connection string if you are trying to connect to MySQL as opposed to SQL Lite. PHPMyAdmin is for MySQL, and I think that is your problem. Your PHP code is attempting to connect to SQL Lite, but you created your database in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I am assuming you created a MySQL database if you used PHPMyAdmin even thought the tags say SQL Lite.*

It looks like you're trying to create an SQL Lite database instead of opening a  connection to your MySQL database.

Change this line to the following

```
//open the database
$db = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=user_db', 'user_username', 'password');
```

Comment: Hello! The reason I did not answer before is because I get the message: "Exception : could not find driver" And I was wondering if maybe the syntax in the script only works for SQLite?

Comment: Looking at Host Gator's docs, it looks like they support PDO, do you have a custom `php.ini` in your website that could be interfering with this?

Comment: I have not made any. Also, when I search through my files, it cannot find any. However, I see that on my cpanel, I can create a custom php.ini file. Is there a certain field I should enable? PS: I am very grateful that you help me with this :)

Comment: Try creating a new php script and put only this one line in it `echo phpinfo();` ... That will tell use what PHP modules HostGator has enabled by default.

Comment: I am an idiot! I wrote MySQL not, mysql.... now, the error is: Exception : SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Comment: Does `user_db` exist in PHPMyAdmin? You need to put the name of your database in that part of your connection string.

Comment: Hey! I used this script from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp and it worked! Thank you for your help! :D